# Environment variables are missing after deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Using Azure DevOps project building Docker image from GitHub and deploying App Service. After deployment all previously environment variables in `App Service -> Configuration -> Application settings` are missing.
Where environment variables should be set not to lose them between deployments?

Comment: Release pipeline >> Deploy App Service task >> Application and Configuration Settings >> App Settings in format `-name "value"`

Comment: As of 2021-01 this seems to be at DevOps > Release pipelines > Edit > Variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where I found:

`Azure DevOps -> Pipelines -> Releases -> Edit -> Tasks -> Azure App Service deploy -> Application and Configuration Settings -> App settings`

Comment: Hi Jonas, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)